# set not being called when editing a collection

Tags: c#, collectioneditor

I have a class containing a collection property which I want to display and edit in a property grid:

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public List<SomeType> Textures
{
    get
    {
        return m_collection;
    }
    set
    {
        m_collection = value;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to edit this collection with the `CollectionEditor`, `set` is never called; why is this and how can I fix it?

I also tried to wrap my `List<SomeType>` in my own collection as described here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/propertygridcollection.aspx

But neither `Add`, nor `Remove` is being called when I add and remove items in the `CollectionEditor`.

Comment: Good question, highlights a common misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setter isn't being called because when you're editting a collection, you're really getting a reference to the original collection and then editting it.

Using your example code, this would only call the getter and then modify the existing collection (never resetting it):

```
var yourClass = new YourClass();
var textures = yourClass.Textures

var textures.Add(new SomeType());
```

To call the setter, you would actually have to assign a new collection to the Property:

```
var yourClass = new YourClass();
var newTextures = new List<SomeType>();
var newTextures.Add(new SomeType());

yourClass.Textures = newTextures;
```

Comment: Bump. And this is why exposing a List instead of an IEnumerable and an AddFoo method is generally considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @annakata Could you elaborate on how to do this in more detail in an answer?

Comment: @annakata I added a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145324/whats-the-correct-way-to-edit-a-collection-in-a-property-grid

Comment: @Andreas - within the context you're interested you have to override things like the CollectionEditor.EditValue method, but I was speaking more generally that you want to encapsulate your List<T> implementation behind a gettable IEnumerable<T> (or ICollection perhaps) and an AddFoo(T foo) method (and/or other CRUD operations). This protects the integrity of the implementation and lets you fall into success.