# What's the correct way to edit a collection in a property grid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a class which is displayed in a property grid. One of the properties is a `List<SomeType>`.

What's the easiest/correct way to set up the code so that I can add and remove items from this collection through the property grid, preferably using the standard `CollectionEditor`.

One of the wrong ways is like this:

[set not being called when editing a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145078/set-not-being-called-when-editing-a-collection)

User annakata suggest that I expose an `IEnumerable` interface instead of a collection. Can someone please provide me with more details?

I have the extra complication that the collection returned by `get` doesn't actually point to a member in my class, but is build on the fly from an other member, something like this:

```
public List<SomeType> Stuff
{
    get
    {
        List<SomeType> stuff = new List<SomeType>();
        //...populate stuff with data from an internal xml-tree
        return stuff;
    }
    set
    {
        //...update some data in the internal xml-tree using value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky one; the solution involves building with the full .NET Framework (since the client-only framework doesn't include `System.Design`). You need to create your own subclass of `CollectionEditor` and tell it what to do with the temporary collection after the UI is finished with it:

```
public class SomeTypeEditor : CollectionEditor {

    public SomeTypeEditor(Type type) : base(type) { }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
        object result = base.EditValue(context, provider, value);

        // assign the temporary collection from the UI to the property
        ((ClassContainingStuffProperty)context.Instance).Stuff = (List<SomeType>)result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you have to decorate your property with the `EditorAttribute`:

```
[Editor(typeof(SomeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public List<SomeType> Stuff {
    // ...
}
```

Long and convoluted, yes, but it works. After you click "OK" on the collection editor popup, you can open it again and the values will remain.

Note: You need to import the namespaces `System.ComponentModel`, `System.ComponentModel.Design` and `System.Drawing.Design`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the type has a public parameterless constructor *it should just work*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class Foo {
    private readonly List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
    public List<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
class Bar {
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form {
            Controls = { new PropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                                            SelectedObject = new Foo()
        }}});
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the collection return from `get` is only a temporary collection built from some other data. I'll edit my question.