# c# PropertyGrid restricting edits on List<T> items

Tags: c#, .net, list, object, propertygrid

I have a app that makes use of the PropertyGrid in C#/.NET

the `PropertGrid` holds onto the `MyAppObject` class/object shown below..

```
class MyAppObject
{
    private List<MyObject> oItems;

    public List<MyObject> Items
    {
        get { return this.oItems; }

    }

}
```

And so far it works well, nice and simple. I want the property grid to allow users to view the items, which it does well, however when you select the property in the PropertyGrid the dialog also allows to add more `List<MyObject> items`.

I do not want this, I only want to have the ability to show the items, not edit them.

I thought by not providing the setter (`set { this.oItems = value; }`):

[image: like this]

then it wouldnt allow the add button.

Hope this makes sense, The screenshots shows the dialog, and I circled the buttons I want to remove.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose it as a read-only list, it should do what you need:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public List<MyObject> Items
{
    get { return this.oItems; }
}
// this (below) is the one the PropertyGrid will use
[DisplayName("Items")]
public ReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> ReadOnlyItems
{
    get { return this.oItems.AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

Note that the members of individual objects (`MyObject` instances) will still be editable, unless you decorate them as `[ReadOnly(true)]`.

As you note, the setter is not necessary to add/remove/edit items. That is because the grid still has full access to the `.Add`, `.Remove` and indexer (`list[index]`) operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly tricky one; the solution involves building with the full .NET Framework (since the client-only framework doesn't include `System.Design`). You need to create your own subclass of `CollectionEditor` and tell it what to do with the temporary collection after the UI is finished with it:

```
public class MyObjectEditor : CollectionEditor {

    public MyObjectEditor(Type type) : base(type) { }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {

        return ((MyObject)context.Instance).Items;
    }
}
```

Then you have to decorate your property with the `EditorAttribute`:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyObjectEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public List<MyObject> Items{
    // ...
}
```

Reference: [What's the correct way to edit a collection in a property grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145324/whats-the-correct-way-to-edit-a-collection-in-a-property-grid)

Alternative:

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection(oItems);
```

OR

```
return oItems.AsReadOnly();
```